# Delphi 2007 - I want to Read an .html file's content and then using ADO Insert or Update a SQL Server 2008 table with the HTML content

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, delphi, tadoquery

I read the data line by line or stream it into a String (cHTML) then using a TADOQuery I use a simple Update or insert query

```
UPDATE Tablename
Set cFieldName = cHTML,
Where a = b
```

The cHTML is basically the HTML file's contents

The errors I get are when a colon in an URL is found the ADO thinks it is a parameter eg: `<a href="https://www....`

Other problems I get are where single quotes in the text at places like the word we've causes the string to not having a closing quote.

Does anyone know how to read an html file's contents into a SQL Server 2008 database using Delphi.

Comment: Use parameters and you'll be fine.

Comment: You must stop what you are doing right now and learn what SQL injection is. Don't resume you current task until this makes you laugh: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters something like this:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE Tablename SET FieldName = :P0');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE a = :P1');
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('P0').Value := cHTML;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('P1').Value := c;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: I have in the mean time created a function to StringReplace certain characters which seams to be working fine:

Comment: function FixADOSQL (s: String): String;
    begin
      s:= StringReplace (s,CHAR(39),CHAR(39)+CHAR(39),[rfReplaceAll]);
      s:= StringReplace (s,'`','''+CHAR(96)+''',[rfReplaceAll]);
      s:= StringReplace (s,'''','''+CHAR(39)+''',[rfReplaceAll]);
      Result:= s;
    end;